# How to stop the horizontal scroll bar from showing when window is resized?

Tags: horizontal-scrolling

I have this website http://www.claybrookeanimalfeeds.co.uk/index.php which I want to be able to keep the content in the middle of the page. Now I've got it so that most of the content stays in the same place when the window re-sizes, however the problem is that when I re-size the window to half the size of the screen, a horizontal scroll bar appears but when you move the scroll bar to the right, there's nothing there and it's just a blank space.

Is there anyway that I can make so that the content stays in the same place without a scroll bar appearing when I re-size the window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using percentages as your widths for the containers, use a pixel value.

Example: `#content { width: 800px }`

Comment: I've tried changing the width of the content box to 800px, but that's made the situation worse. When I re-size the window, I still get the scroll bar at the bottom of the window, but now I get a scroll bar at the bottom of the page as well.

I'd like the header, menu and the footer to be the width of the page (that's why I've used percentages for width) but I'd like the bits in the content box to stay in the middle.

Comment: Actually after testing it. IE seems to handle the re-sizing fine but it's on Firefox and chrome that I'm having the scroll bar problem.

Comment: You'll need to work on your containers and child elements widths.

Comment: After quite a bit of fiddling around (I've been working on other features of the site), I just put a min-width of 960px on the wrap div and it does what I what it to do. So I will accept this as the answer as it is very similar to what I have done.